# Reset CSS Stars from Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following code, which allows a user to select a rating value and this works without issue. On the first selection, all stars are grey.

However if a user goes and rates a second thing, it doesn't retain the value but it does retain the previous number of yellow stars.

How do I reset it so no stars are yellow - I'm looking for a Javascript solution to this.

```js
var rating = {}

function rate(value) {
  rating.starValue = Number(value);
}
```

```css
.stars,
.stars label::before
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.stars label:hover,
.stars label:hover ~ label
{
    color: #b5cebe;
}

.stars input
{
    display: none;
}

.stars
{
    direction: rtl;
}

.stars label
{
    color: #ccc;
}

.stars label::before
{
    content: "\2605";
    width: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.stars input:checked ~ label
{
    color: #f5b301;
}
```

```html
<div class="stars">
            <input type="radio" name="stars-1" id="stars-1-0" value="5" onclick="rate(this.value)"/><label for="stars-1-0"></label><!--
          --><input type="radio" name="stars-1" id="stars-1-1" value="4" onclick="rate(this.value)"/><label for="stars-1-1"></label><!--
          --><input type="radio" name="stars-1" id="stars-1-2" value="3" onclick="rate(this.value)"/><label for="stars-1-2"></label><!--
          --><input type="radio" name="stars-1" id="stars-1-3" value="2" onclick="rate(this.value)"/><label for="stars-1-3"></label><!--
          --><input type="radio" name="stars-1" id="stars-1-4"  value="1" onclick="rate(this.value)"/><label for="stars-1-4"></label>
        </div>
```

Edit: Before folks down vote this (presumably because they think I've not attempted to resolve this on my own), I've been trying to figure this out for over an hour, the primary issue I have is I can't figure out which DOM selector to use. As I've been hammering on this for over an hour, then I have no concise way of putting all the combinations that I've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to figure out how do you want to reset the radio button set i.e may be you have a reset button or you can toggle between the selected and unselected states.
Below is the code to just reset the radio buttons assuming an event for reset action.

```
var ratings = document.getElementsByName('stars-1');
ratings.forEach(function(element)
{
  element.checked=false
})
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I'll handle the calling in my JS code without a button but I was struggling to it to select right bit and reset the right thing!  It now makes perfect sense after seeing your solution.

Answer (score 0):

There you go :)

`querySelectorAll` [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```js
var rating = {}

function rate(value) {
  rating.starValue = Number(value);
}

function reset() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.stars input[name=stars-1]');
  elements.forEach(function(element) {
    element.checked = false;
  });

  rating = {}
}
```

```css
.stars,
.stars label::before
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.stars label:hover,
.stars label:hover ~ label
{
    color: #b5cebe;
}

.stars input
{
    display: none;
}

.stars
{
    direction: rtl;
}

.stars label
{
    color: #ccc;
}

.stars label::before
{
    content: "\2605";
    width: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.stars input:checked ~ label
{
    color: #f5b301;
}
```

```html
<div class="stars">
            <input type="radio" name="stars-1" id="stars-1-0" value="5" onclick="rate(this.value)"/><label for="stars-1-0"></label><!--
          --><input type="radio" name="stars-1" id="stars-1-1" value="4" onclick="rate(this.value)"/><label for="stars-1-1"></label><!--
          --><input type="radio" name="stars-1" id="stars-1-2" value="3" onclick="rate(this.value)"/><label for="stars-1-2"></label><!--
          --><input type="radio" name="stars-1" id="stars-1-3" value="2" onclick="rate(this.value)"/><label for="stars-1-3"></label><!--
          --><input type="radio" name="stars-1" id="stars-1-4"  value="1" onclick="rate(this.value)"/><label for="stars-1-4"></label>
        </div>
        
        <input type='button' onclick='reset()' value='reset'>
```